# how to store python console output in python variable

Tags: python-3.x

below is my code :

```
def combinationUtil(arr, n, r,index, data, i): 
    if(index == r): 
      for j in range(r): 
        print(data[j], end = " ") 
      print(" ") 
      return
 if(i >= n): 
    return
data[index] = arr[i] 
combinationUtil(arr, n, r, index + 1, data, i + 1) 
combinationUtil(arr, n, r, index, data, i + 1) 
def printcombination(arr, n, r): 
    data = list(range(r)) 
    combinationUtil(arr, n, r, 0, data, 0) 
 var = []
 pp = 5
 r = 3
 arr = []
for i in range(1, pp+1):
    arr.append(i)
 n = len(arr)

 printcombination(arr, n, r)
```

it gives me this output:

1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 5
1 3 4
1 3 5
1 4 5
2 3 4
2 3 5
2 4 5
3 4 5
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 5
1 3 4
1 3 5
1 4 5
2 3 4
2 3 5
2 4 5
3 4 5

i want to save this output as a variable in python

Comment: Do you want to have that variable in the script writing the output or in another script that calls that one (unmodified)?

Comment: Hi Sir, i have edited my post. now it might represent my query clearly.

Comment: The code is somewhat helpful, but my structural question remains unaddressed.

Comment: no sir, just want to store the output as variable in python and i will perform further operation on the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have a combination utility routine that produces the output of interest.

If you were calling someone else's routine, you might need to assign
`sys.stdout` to an `io.StringIO()` to capture the output.

But as it stands, you have control over the source code,
so you can easily replace

```
      for j in range(r):
          print(data[j], end=' ')
      print(' ')
```

with the following more convenient interface:

```
      yield [data[j] for j in range(r)]
```

Then iterate, e.g.:

```
for row in combinationUtil(arr, n, r, 0, list(range(r)), 0):
    print(row)
```

Cf [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

Comment: Hi Sir, i did as suggested but i am getting this error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\combi.py", line 65, in <module>
    for row in printcombination(arr, n, r):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: That's right, the printcombination routine would need to conform to the revised API, as well. For example it could iterate and `yield`. I side stepped the issue by just inline expanding it in my updated answer, calling combinationUtil directly. Please `$ pip install flake8` and follow the advice of both `$ flake8 *.py` and PEP-8. For example, a snake_case `combination_util` identifier would be more appropriate. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/